# Inheritance in MVC5

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm using MVC5, and have gotten CaptchaMvc nuget package.
I want to use function `IsCaptchaValid` from this package in my controller.
This is the signature of the function

```
public static bool IsCaptchaValid(this ControllerBase controllerBase, string errorText, params ParameterModel[] parameters);
```

From here, when I go to definition of `ControllerBase`, I get to see that this class is part of `System.Web.Mvc`, v5.2.3.0.

When I go to my controller, I see that it inherits from `BaseController` (my class), and that this class inherits from `AsyncController` class, that is abstract, and also part of `System.Web.Mvc` namespace. When I go to definition of this class I see that it inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`, and that this class inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase`.

My question is, how is it that I cannot use function `IsCaptchaValid` in my controller?
Is it because of the abstract `AsyncController`, and if so, why should abstract class hide funcitons?
Is there a way that would allow me to use this function without making my controller inheritance hierarchy?

UPDATE 1:
As Richard Deeming mentioned
[image]
I am using CaptchaMvc namespace needed for this function to work, but VS doesn't seem to recognize that I installed it, even though I can clearly see that I did in Nuget Package Manager for this project.

Comment: So long as you have a `using` statement for the namespace containing the `static` class where your extension method is defined, you should be able to use it as if it were an instance method of your controller. If it's not working, you'll need to show the code that attempts to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I just needed to restart Visual Studio...

Comment: Unfortunately, restarting VS seems to fix a lot of these types of issues all too often.